# Oracle Database 12c - Change SYS Password

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We have an Oracle Database 12c instance on Windows 2012 R2. Recently we tried changing the SYS password. The change was successful, but strange thing is that the old password still works. We even tried putting random passwords for SYS user and all the passwords work. We were able to change password for SYSTEM and SYSMAN etc but can anyone help with this SYS password issue we're having?

Thanks,

Comment: How and from where do you connect using the old password?

Comment: We have tried old password on the db server itself, also from the client side, works from both - it's just not the old password that works for SYS, any password we try works with SYS user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're authenticating as a user belonging to the dba group. Try going to the users groups and remove your user. When you authenticate as sysdba or sysoper, Oracle first validates if your user belongs to the dba group.

Answer (score 0):

In 12c database , password file location is under ASM (If asm is used) not under $ORACLE_HOME/dbs.

Oracle ignores the password, while connecting from user sys, from the server where database has been created.

Answer (score 0):

Log on to your Windows server as a member of the Administrators group or a member of the ORA_DBA group.

Open command prompt as administrator & try the below steps

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect / as sysdba
Once connected, you can change the SYS password to something you know: 
ALTER USER sys IDENTIFIED BY new_password;
```